# Recycler View Not scrolled with another view in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Recycler View Not scrolled with another view in android studio.
when i scroll with recycler view element , it scrolled well , but when i scrolled from another view . recycler view element not scrolled even if many recycler view elements are remaining.

i want to scroll fully from another view too.

Comment: Please read [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have two image view in an linear layout under a  scrollView . and one recycler view . there are 30+ elements in recyclerview . when we scroll through recycler view elements . its scroll only recycler view element . i want that whole view behave like one scrollview not two . i want if we scroll through any recycler view element it scrolls whole view.